# SwiftUI Picker out of frame

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to style a picker in my SwiftUI app. For some reason it seems to cut off about halfway down, and empty grey space is filled above (as shown below)

[image]

My code for styling is:

```
Form {
    Picker("Select", selection: $viewModel.type) {
        ForEach(viewModel.typeOptions, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
    }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
}
.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 60, alignment: .top)
.position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
```

Obviously using a GeometryReader for the height and width values. No matter where I position it on the screen, it displays the same half cut off as shown in the picture, so it is not like the next component is cutting it off. I thought the `alignment: .top` would do the trick by moving the picker to the top of the frame, but that doesn't seem to have the right effect. Any help would be appreciated.